# LastIndexOf function usage

Tags: java, lastindexof

I am trying to learn how to use `lastIndexOf` function, but the code doesn't work for me. After clicked the button, I just get the whole text, not only the extension.  What am I doing wrong?

```
private  String getExtension(String s)
{
    char dot='.';
    int pos=s.lastIndexOf("dot");
    String root=s.substring(pos+1);
    return root;   
}


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{               
    String s=jTextField1.getText();
    jLabel1.setText(getExtension(s));
}
```

Comment: You don't have a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your problem

You need to remove the quotation marks around the variable name.

```
int pos=s.lastIndexOf("dot");
```

becomes

```
int pos=s.lastIndexOf(dot);
```

#### Just an aside

This could have been worked out, VERY easily by yourself if you'd used a debugger. I can't help but feel you've used SO as a first resort, rather than what it should be; a place to go when you've really exhausted all methods of investigation that you are personally aware of.

**A debugger**

Almost every single IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans etc) have something called a debugger. A debugger allows you to go through your program line by line, and see the value of every single variable as the program develops. If you're using Eclipse, on the toolbar along the top, select `Run -> Debug`, to initialize the program in debugging mode. For Netbeans, there is a debug button on the right of the Run button (The play symbol). Just a few examples.

Comment: Please read my edit, and mark one of the two answers as correct so this question can be closed.

Comment: Igor if were an expert i woudnt be here You can understand this by looking this basic code.i am an absolute beginner my  smart friend you are here  to make fun of people or help or why?

Comment: I apologize if you didn;t know about the debugger, which is why I included an explanation of how to use it, but I think that the way I worded my edit wasn't offensive at all.

Comment: Chris i am sorry but i dont know how to mark the answers as correct i havent seen any buttons

Comment: It is a hollow tick next to each answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the quotes in your `lastIndexOf` statement.

```
int pos=s.lastIndexOf("dot");
//                    ^---^
//                      +---------- Take those " out
```